# Загнать в переменную часть названия файла средствами PHP

Tags: php

Есть файл, название которого состоит из 2 частей, разделённых знаком `+`. К примеру:

```
$filename = abc+klm.jpg
```

Нужно создать переменную с первой частью названия до `+`, то есть в данном примере — `abc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$rtfm = explode("+", $filename)[0]` например.